# Testing an application under Eclipse with sudo elevation

Tags: root, debugging, eclipse

I am developing a C++ application that requires root privilege. I am working under Eclipse and I would like to be able to launch/debug from it.

I know I could start Eclipse as a root, but I am looking for other options, such as somehow requesting the elevation in the launch configurations.

Any idea ?

---

Note that my question is not about how to discourage myself to debug with root privilege.

Comment: It might be dangerous to run a a program as `root` that is likely to contain errors. I suggest to debug the program with modifications and/or in a special testing environment that allow running it without `root` privilege. I suggest to [edit] the question and add details about the program why it needs to run as `root` to get more specific hints how to do this. Maybe you can run the program with `gdbserver` as `root` outside eclipse or as an external tool from Eclipse, and use `gdbserver` based "remote" debugging in Eclipse.

Comment: how does eclipse run the compiled application ? can you trick command line from `./myapp` to `sudo /absolute/path/to/mypapp` (and edit `/etc/sudoers` accordinlgy) ?

Comment: @Bodo: this is required by a third-party library, that's all I know. I want to work from Eclipse, this is why I am asking the question.

Comment: @Archemar: I have no idea how Eclipse does. Spawning a process ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Please add all requested information or clarification to the question, don't use comments for this purpose. Adding to my previous comment: It might be possible to add something like `sudo gdbserver other_args... your_program` as an external tool (green button with red toolbox) and use remote debugging, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/4038760/10622916.

Comment: Running your whole program as `root` because a third-party library suppoosedly requires this, is a risk. You should consider dropping the privilege and regaining it only when calling the library functions using `setreuid` or similar. It might be possible to make the library functions work with other means, e.g. assigning a supplementary group to the users that are allowed to use the programs. You could try to analyze with a system call trace why the library might fail when it does not run as `root` to find out about possible ways to avoid running the program as root.

Comment: @Bodo: not supposedly. Effectively.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Are you sure that running the proram as root is the only way to make the library functions work? I wrote "supposedly" because I have experience with a program where the documentation told me that it must be run as `root`, while I found out that it was possible to run it as a normal user after assigning a supplementary group to this user. Apparently the author did not think about the exact permissions needed for the program to run. Of course it highly depends on what your "secret" library actually does.

Comment: @Bodo: I have no intent to waste time on this investigation. If there is no easy solution, running Eclipse as root is good enough.

Comment: would you rather waste time later fixing your install if/when your possibly-incorrect program run as root breaks something?

Comment: @Esther: right. (Anyway it will not.) Thank you for your contribution.